# Obtain an array from an Object

Tags: c#, arrays, class, object

I have the following class definition.

```
public class people
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name  { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_of_birth  { get; set; }
}
```

I've then created an array of people as follows:

```
    people[] the_people = new people[3];
    the_people[0].first_name="Tony";
    the_people[0].last_name="Carrot";
    the_people[0].date_of_birth=new DateTime(1959-03-16);
    the_people[1].first_name="Joe";
    the_people[1].last_name="Tomato";
    the_people[1].date_of_birth=new DateTime(1963-06-2);
    the_people[2].first_name="Tarina";
    the_people[2].last_name="Wends";
    the_people[2].date_of_birth=new DateTime(1982-11-22);
```

How can I store the first_names of the_people object in a **new string array** such that an output like the following is obtained. Is this possible via linq

```
string[] the_peoples_first_names=new string[3] {"Tony","Joe","Tarina"};
```

Similarly how would I obtain an array of date times to store the date of births of all people in a separate DateTime array.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: @JohnSaunders If everyone new the answer to all questions nobody would be asking on this website + I don't want to make my posts overly long and boring so no-one would be interested in reading it. These kind of posts are unconstructive... But that's my opinion of which I am entitled too.

Comment: Sure. And you still didn't bother to tell us what you had tried. That might have shown us what problem you were having. It might even have shown _you_ the core of the problem you were having.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The problem was listed above, If you had read it and understood it you might have tried answering it like the kind people below. They understood it quite clearly , rather than spamming my question.

Comment: @PeterH John is a smart dude, I'm sure he understood your question. John is just trying to help you write a better question. I happened to get lucky, but it isn't uncommon for someone to spend time writing an answer, then the asker say, "Oh yeah - I tried that, it didn't work". It's helpful for us to know what you have tried, just so we know where to start.

Comment: @vcsjones is correct. By "showing us what you tried", you would have made it clear what part of the solution you didn't understand. Did you not understand projection (as it happened), or did you now know about `.ToArray()`, did you not understand LINQ syntax at all? Any of those were possible based on your question, and I wanted you to show us the specific problem you were having, in hopes of narrowing it down and getting you a better answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be done with LINQ. What you are basically asking for is a *projection*.

[MSDN describes a projection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546168.aspx) as this:

> Projection refers to the operation of transforming an object into a new form that often consists only of those properties that will be subsequently used. By using projection, you can construct a new type that is built from each object. You can project a property and perform a mathematical function on it. You can also project the original object without changing it.

So we want to project the objects in your `the_people` array into a new array. The documentation recommends using the `Select` LINQ operator:

```
var the_people_names = the_people.Select(p => p.first_name);
```

What goes inside of the `Select` is a delegate, often in the form of a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) or anonymous delegate.

But we aren't quite there yet. `Select` is just a deferred evaluation that creates an enumerable sequence. It does not return an array. To create an array, we use [`.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var the_people_names_array = the_people.Select(p => p.first_name).ToArray();
```

You can use this approach to any property of `people` class, including the date of birth.

You can learn more about LINQ on MSDN on the [LINQ about page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

```
var firstNames = the_people.Select(p => p.first_name).ToArray();
var dates_of_birth = the_people.Select(p => p.date_of_birth).ToArray();
```